# Highest possible FPS configuration for CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I come from a CS 1.6  background and primarily play that. I've just recently acquired CS:GO and I enjoy it somewhat but would like to know what config commands I can apply to squeeze as much FPS out of the game that I can. I don't care how it looks; In fact, I'd actually like it looking much ... simpler.

As for more info, I currently play on my laptop which has a less than par ATI Mobility Radeon HD 45xx GPU. My aim is only for a solid as possible 60 fps but in firefights it tends to dip down to the 40s and sometimes 30s. I've even noticed some actual GPU Load (~95%) which never happened with CS 1.6 at all. In  addition, I've already went into the advanced video settings and set everything to low and my resolution to 640. Thank you.

Comment: CS:GO's version of the Source engine is many, many times more powerful than GoldSrc.  Knowing that series of GPUs, you may have reached its limit.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if these exist, but 3rd party lower resolution textures might help. If you've lowered everything you possibly could, your only option is texture replacement and console commands I'm afraid.

To the downvoter: Feel free to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, for the response. I was hoping that someone actually had some tried and true commands (much like corpsestay or minmodels in 1.6) Well, I suppose I could put some elbow grease to it.